# Use API call in component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, axios

I am playing around with VueJS and trying to make an api call from within a component:

```
var postView = {
    props: ['post'],
    template: '<li>{{ post.title }}</li>',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    data: function () {
        return {
            results: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.results = response.data
        })
    },
    ready: function () { },
    methods: {}
}

Vue.component('postitem', postView);

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {},
    ready: function () { },
    methods: {}

})
```

I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "results" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render.

I am wondering what the best approach is to make api calls from within a component and display it on a HTML page. I learned that a component’s data option must be a function, but I'm not sure what the error related to 'results' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should consider using vue single file components. They are great for splitting your functionality.
[Vue requests guide](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=btDfVBPYI-U&index=34&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa&t=0s)

You can watch the whole playlist for complete vue guide. The link is to the video that explains api calls in vue.

Answer (score 0):

i think that error for (this)

you can do like that:

```
var vm = this;
axios.get(url).then(response => {
        vm.results = response.data
 })
```